# Cannot get Variable value in Jenkins Environment variable

Tags: windows, jenkins

I am trying to add timestamp to the filename in a Jenkins job. The command looks like this.

```
"C:\TricentisTosca\cijobscript\%execution_conf_path%.xml" -r "%WORKSPACE%\Tosca_result\Agent_%BUILD_NUMBER%.xml"
```

This works for the BUILD_NUMBER environment variable, however when I try to use TAG_DATE etc..it doesn't.
So,

`"C:\TricentisTosca\cijobscript\%execution_conf_path%.xml" -r "%WORKSPACE%\Tosca_result\Agent_%TAG_DATE%.xml"` doesn't work.

No other variable gives it's value. When I use `echo` to check, it simply says `echo is ON` and doesn't print the value of the Variable

Can someone let me know what am I missing here?

Comment: Can you share your pipeline code?

Comment: @NoamHelmer That is the code. I see that you can use a script to create a variable. However, each step has it's own environment so I am figuring out how make the script variable..globally available to all the build steps.